# Erro ao carregar fonte: OTS Parsing error: cmap: Failed to parse format 4

Tags: css3, css-font-face

Estou tendo problema para que o browser use um fonte personalizada! Na pasta css eu tenho a pasta fonts, e dentro da pasta fonts está o arquivo `prompt.ttf` porém na hora que subo o arquivo pro servidor, eu faço o teste e a fonte não aparece. Ela é substituída pela fonte padrão `sans-serif`.

Código no CSS do INDEX:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'prompt';
src: url('fonts/prompt.ttf');
}
#name {
font-family: 'prompt', sans-serif; 
font-size:10px;
text-indent:10px;
text-align:left;
z-index:1;
position:absolute;
font-weight:normal;
width:120px;
height:20px;
top:110px;
right:75px;
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
border: 0px solid #000000;
}
```

**Print do erro:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: tenta usar https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator, e muda o seu css, não custa tentar haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De fato resolvi o erro adicionando o formato da fonte que queria usar, (true type).

Ficou assim o CSS:

```
font-family: 'prompt';
src: url('fonts/prompt.ttf') format('truetype');
```

Testei com open type e também funcionou:

```
font-family: 'menufont';
src: url('fonts/myriad.otf') format('opentype');
```

Enfim, era só adicionar o format que parava o erro!